# PHP: package/template for wrapping web form/app around a server's shell script

Tags: php, security, exec, wrapper

I'd like to provide simple public web/GET access to a shell script with many flags.  The user enters through their browser into fields that correspond to arguments, or just writes a GET request. When they submit, PHP cleans that input and calls system or exec for my script with those args, and returns the output ugly style in  tags.

I already know how to do this amateur-style, but I haven't been deep in PHP since it had an awful reputation for security. There were a million gotchas back then. 
 On top of that, I know that giving users such direct access to the shell can be a huge security risk.  With all that, it feels kind of reckless to just go ahead and write this application without being an expert at PHP security.

Fortunately, it seems like using PHP to write an API for a shell script would be a very common enough task that someone who knows what they are doing has already done right.  In the best case, I can work from their code and feel secure.  But I'm obviously not googling for the right keywords, because I can't find anything that fits. Any recommendations on packages/templates/examples I can leverage?

**Duplicate search**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931286/securely-using-the-php-exec-function) already, but it seems to mostly say "yes, it's risky".  It doesn't offer much accounting of the risks, nor template code for performing this very general task safely. Of course, it does make me realize that the scope of my question is huge.  Assume that my script has no combination of parameters that could make it grind to a halt and doesn't write to disk, only to screen.  Unless you tell me otherwise, I'm mostly worried about mitigating against malicious inputs and against people somehow using insecure PHP globals to do inscrutable awful things that I never worked my head around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your script controls the arguments it receives and handles, and maybe do some sanity checks on the ones that might cause problem with your shell script, and you escape the arguments you've received, you should be pretty safe.

Example PHP script:

```
<?php

$path_to_executable = '/bin/ls';

$command = [];
$command[] = escapeshellarg($path_to_executable);

if (isset($_GET['arg1'])) {
    if ($_GET['arg1'] > 1000) {
        echo "Error: Please don't specify an 'arg1' higher than 1000.";
        exit(1);
    }
}

$supported_args = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'];
foreach ($supported_args as $arg) {
    if (isset($_GET[$arg])) {
        $command[] = "--$arg " . escapeshellarg($_GET[$arg]);
    }
}

$command = implode($command, ' ');
echo "Executing $command ...\n";
exec($command . " 2>&1", $result, $return_val);
echo "Returned value: $return_val\n";
echo "Result: " . implode("\n", $result);
```

Example usage:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:3000/51912835.php?arg1=test&arg3=patate&arg4=no'
Executing '/bin/ls' --arg1 'test' --arg3 'patate' ...
Returned value: 2
Result: /bin/ls: unrecognized option '--arg1'
Try '/bin/ls --help' for more information.
```